# What's next? Think laterally

Tags: lateral-thinking, sequence

What is next in this sequence?

> V
>
> I V
>
> I I I V
>
> I I I I I V
>
> V I I V
>
> I V I I I I V

?

Answer is one of the following three options

A: I I I V I V I I V

B: I I I V I I I I I I V

C: V I I I V

#### Hint

> Not a math question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the next element is

> I I I V I V I I V

Because

> This is a [look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) using Roman numerals.
>  For example the first term is V, this is one V or I V which is the next term.
>  The last given element is I V I I I I V which is one I, one V, four Is and one V or I I I V I V I I V.

Comment: That was amazingly quick @hexomino.  Dang.

Comment: Took your suggestion

Comment: @DEEM you said it's not a math question but look-and-say sequence IS math.

Comment: My thought was that there are no math operations so really not a math problem @netrox

Answer (score 2):

I think the next element is

> I I I V I V I I V

Because

> The pattern I see is that a V generates 1 I then adds two Is to the left. When the total amount of Is is 5 then the leftmost three are converted to a new V.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! hexomino had already given this answer fourteen hours before you posted it. Please try and make sure that you're not re-posting answers that have already been given.

Comment: @F1Krazy These answers are different.  If Ruben continued to apply his pattern, the next sequence number would be "I I I I I V I I I V I I I I V" (there is no rule for "I I V" so "I V" would add two I's to the left, becoming "I I I I V"), whereas Hexomino would get "I I I I I V I I I V I I I I I V" (five I's on the far right vs four).